# Python the same char not equals

Tags: python, unicode

I have text in my database. I send some text from xhr to my view. Function find does not find some unicode chars.

I want to find selected text using:

```
text.find(selection)
```

but sometimes variable 'selection' contains a char like that:

```
ę  # in xhr unichr(281)
```

whereas in variable 'text' there was:

```
ę  # in db has two chars unichr(101) + unichr(808)
```

They are just different forms of the same thing. How to make `.find` work more reliably here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) might help you.

Basically if you normalize the data coming from the db, and normalize your selection to the same form, you should have a better result when using `str.find`, `str.__contains__` (i.e. `in`), `str.index`, and friends.

```
>>> u1 = chr(281)
>>> u2 = chr(101) + chr(808)
>>> print(u1, u2)
ę ę
>>> u1 == u2
False
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u2) == u1
True
```

NFC stands for the *Normal Form Composed* form.  You can read up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) for some description of the other possible forms.