# emojis.get() isn't working when looping through a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, for-loop, emoji

I am trying to use `emojis.get() != set()` to determine if an emoji is in a string. When used on individual strings, it always works; however, it only works on certain emojis when looping through the characters of a string or strings in a list. (This isn't my actual code, just a simplified example of what's happening):

```
for i in 'Game ✔️':
    print(i, type(i), emojis.get(i), emojis.get(i) != set())
print('✔️', type('✔️'), emojis.get('✔️'), emojis.get('✔️') != set())
#Out:
#G <class 'str'> set() False
#a <class 'str'> set() False
#m <class 'str'> set() False
#e <class 'str'> set() False
#  <class 'str'> set() False
#✔ <class 'str'> set() False
#<class 'str'> set() False
#✔️ <class 'str'> {'✔️'} True

for i in 'Game ':
    print(i, type(i), emojis.get(i), emojis.get(i) != set())
print('', type(''), emojis.get(''), emojis.get('') != set())
#Out:
#G <class 'str'> set() False
#a <class 'str'> set() False
#m <class 'str'> set() False
#e <class 'str'> set() False
#  <class 'str'> set() False
# <class 'str'> {''} True
# <class 'str'> {''} True


j = []
for i in 'Game ✔️':
    j.append(i)
for k in j:
    print(k, emojis.get(k))
print(j)
#Out:
#G set()
#a set()
#m set()
#e set()
#  set()
#✔ set()
#️ set()
#['G', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', '✔', '️']

j = []
for i in 'Game ':
    j.append(i)
for k in j:
    print(k, emojis.get(k))
print(j)
#Out:
#G set()
#a set()
#m set()
#e set()
#  set()
# {''}
#['G', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', '']
```

I'm not sure what the ️️ is after the checkmark or why it is being added to the list as an empty string.

Edit: 
I am now using `len(emoji.demojize()) > 1 or character == ''` instead of `emojis.get() != set()` after DYZ's comment about the invisible character. I could not figure out how to fix the problem still using the emojis package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some emojis (e.g. ☁) have two unicode, u'\u2601' and u'\u2601\ufe0f'. What does u'\ufe0f' mean? Is it the same if I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100329/some-emojis-e-g-have-two-unicode-u-u2601-and-u-u2601-ufe0f-what-does)

Comment: There is an extra invisible character 0xfe0f in the string with the checkmark.

Comment: I don't think the article helped with this problem, but I am new to coding so it might help someone who knows more than I do. I just edited with my solution after I couldn't figure out how to deal with the invisible character while still using the emojis package.