# Why are the strings not equal after I slice out card suit emoji?

Tags: python, unicode

Python 3.9

```python
cards = ['♥️A','♠️2','♣️3']
ref_list = ['A','2','3']

for a in cards:
    print(a[1:])
    print(a[1:] in ref_list)
```

the output is

```text
A
False
️2
False
️3
False
```

How should I revise the code to make it work? (Make the output `True`?)

Comment: What does the sentence 'make it work' mean? In other terms, what is the expected output? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The point is    '♥️A'[1:]  the output is 'A' , but this 'A' is not identical to the str 'A'. I cannot tell the difference by eye. Maybe there's some harsh difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Unicode!

```
>>> len('♥️A')
3

>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in '♥️A']
['0x2665', '0xfe0f', '0x41']

>>> '♥️A'[0:1]
'♥'

>>> '♥️A'[0:2]
'♥️'
```

The red heart in this string is composed of the [Black Heart Suit](https://unicode-table.com/en/2665/) and the [Variation Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38100927/288201) code points, so your complete string has 3 code points.

Consider [not using string concatenation](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) to represent this data, and define a dataclass or at least a tuple like `('♥️', 'A')` instead.

Comment: Or use the module `unicodedata` and check the class: Do not split before a `M` class