# Python subprocess issues with asterisk and wildcards when encoding file name

Tags: python, linux, unicode, subprocess, imagemagick

I'm trying to write a file with a Unicode file name, `*️⃣.png`, inside a folder with other image files.

In UTF-8, this gets encoded to `*\xef\xb8\x8f\xe2\x83\xa3.png`. The asterisk is causing some issues with `subprocess`. It appears to be acting as a wildcard in a glob.

The following code reproduces the issue:

```py
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

ICON_CACHE_PATH = Path('/tmp')

icon_path_9 = Path(ICON_CACHE_PATH / '9️⃣.png')
icon_path_star = Path(ICON_CACHE_PATH / '*️⃣.png')
subprocess.call([
    'convert', '-pointsize', '64', '-background', 'transparent',
    f'pango:{icon_path_9.stem}', icon_path_9
])
subprocess.call([
    'convert', '-pointsize', '64', '-background', 'transparent',
    f'pango:{icon_path_star.stem}', icon_path_star
])
print(icon_path_star.exists())
```

Instead of creating both `*️⃣.png` and `9️⃣.png`, with the images of the Unicode characters, I end up with a single file `9️⃣.png`, with an asterisk in it.

The above code prints `False`.

How can I create both files, with the correct images?

[Edit] This is probably just a *ImageMagick* issue. Running other binaries, such as `stat`, on this file works fine. I just used a temporary file name for *ImageMagick*, and used *Python* to rename it again. Although any suggestions for how to escape it in *ImageMagick* is welcome.

Comment: `\xef\xb8\x8f` is actually the Unicode "variation" character `+UFE0F`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100329/what-does-u-ufe0f-in-an-emoji-mean-is-it-the-same-if-i-delete-it#38100927).

Comment: Can you run `convert` command directly in a bash shell, to see if `*️⃣.png` gets generated ?

Comment: @Philippe I tried it in *Zsh*. `*️⃣.png` doesn't get generated. The same problem occurs. Adding quotes doesn't help.

Comment: Is `convert` a binary program or a script ?