# How can I make a Python string to include unicode code points?

Tags: python, unicode

I want to have an ASCII representation of a string that could contain non-ascii characters such as German umlauts. The way the non-ascii characters should be encoded is as unicode code points, e.g. `ß` would be `\u00df`.

The problem is that I have those escape sequences in my database. It gets displayed like I want it, but when the user searches for something, he enters  `ß` and not `\u00df`. For `ß`, it works for me to simply make `search_query.replace('ß', r'\u00df')`, but there are (many) more possible escape sequences.

### What I tried

```
>>> name = 'Ein Spaß'
>>> name.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')
b'Ein Spa\\xdf'
>>> name.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
b'Ein Spa&#223;'
```

What I want to get:

```
'Ein Spa\\u00df'
```

Comment: `The problem is that I have those escape sequences in my database. It gets displayed like I want it..` Could you elaborate what this portion means? Do you mean to say the string stored in your database is `'Ein Spa\\u00df'`? If so, ideally shouldn't that be fixed? Or if the string is stored correctly, but being incorrectly read, there's issues in the pipeline.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing it the other way round? I mean, converting in your select the escape sequences in the database to the character representation?

Comment: `Do you mean to say the string stored in your database is 'Ein Spa\\u00df'? If so, ideally shouldn't that be fixed?`

Yes and yes, but that is not possible in this case. I only have read access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a dumb workaround, stdlib `json` encoding will use the 4 digit unicode escapes:

```
>>> name = 'Ein Spaß'
>>> json.dumps(name)
'"Ein Spa\\u00df"'
>>> ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(name)) == name
True
```

However, this will not really solve your search problem robustly. You'll need to normalize the query text before searching. And you'll want to normalize unicode data on the way into the database, too - or use a db + ORM which handles such details for you.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36137602/674039) for details about a better tool for the job here: [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).

Answer (score 0):

encode in ascii if possible
else replace by code point as unicode string
ord : is a function to get character code point as integer base 10

```
new=[] 
for e in name: 
    try: 

        new.append(e.encode("ascii").decode()) 
    except: 

        new.append(u"\\u%04x"%ord(e)) 
"".join(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data in your database is stored as escaped unicode, you can use [`codecs.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode) with encoding set to [`unicode_escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings):

```
>>> name = "Ein Spa\\u00df"
>>> codecs.decode(name, "unicode_escape")
'Ein Spaß'
```